# Table not rendered fully after 470 rows in Yii

Tags: php, html, yii, apache2

I have about 240 rows in a database. I'm trying to generate a matrix from the data with color-coded cells. However, the matrix is never fully-generated all the time. When removing a few rows, it completely renders the matrix. What seems to be the problem with this?

Comment: Do you check table render on other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your request line plus header fields size? This can be caused because it exceeds 8190 Bytes. 
This also explains why when you remove some rows it renders completely.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, please provide additional information.